# MySql multiple results tables for each unique values

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry if the title is not well explained tried my best.

I currently have this transactions table which hold the records, every row has an agent and a currency assigned to it.

| id | amount | agent | currency_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 400.00 | agent1 | 1 |
| 2 | 170.00 | agent5 | 3 |
| 3 | 110.00 | agent4 | 2 |
| 4 | 430.00 | agent5 | 3 |
| 5 | 155.00 | agent1 | 1 |
| 6 | 370.00 | agent2 | 2 |
| 7 | 10.00 | agent2 | 2 |
| 8 | 150.00 | agent1 | 1 |
| 9 | 130.00 | agent3 | 3 |
| 10 | 445.00 | agent4 | 2 |

And this other table called currency which holds the unique currency and name.

| id | currency |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | USD |
| 2 | VES |
| 3 | EUR |

The query that I want to make is a SUM and group by agent for every currency there is. I am able to do it with a single query like this but only for one currency in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT a.agent, 
       SUM(a.amount) 
FROM transactions AS a 
INNER JOIN currency AS b ON b.id = a.currency_id
WHERE b.currency = 'VES'
GROUP BY a.agent
```

I will be getting this result which is only for the VES currency

| agent | total |
| --- | --- |
| agent2 | 380.00 |
| agent4 | 555.00 |

I am looking for one query that allow me to get the result of all 3 current existing currencies (USD, VES, EUR) this should give a result of 3 different tables

Comment: Tip of today: choose table aliases that make sense, e.g. `t` for `transactions`.

Comment: What you'd like is 3 differents table for the results ? 1 table for each currency ?

Comment: Yes, 1 table for each currency, each currency should be separated

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want a report showing all agents, currencies, and their sums.  You may try using this cross join approach:

```sql
SELECT a.agent, c.currency, COALESCE(SUM(t.amount), 0) AS total
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT agent FROM transactions) a
CROSS JOIN currency c
LEFT JOIN transactions t
    ON t.agent = a.agent AND
       t.currency_id = c.id
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

The first two tables in the join generate all combinations of agents and currencies.  We join this to your transactions table and aggregate to get the totals.